# Trying to make curves follow points

Tags: geometry-nodes

This vertical lines are instanced lines and I'm trying to make horizontal lines that go from one point to the other of same index (since the lines are instanced, points with same height have same index), in other words: to make a fence. How to make the horizontal lines to follow the trail? The ideal would be to create curves with multiple points based on other points positions, but without such feature, I'm trying to instance lines to follow the curve shape. Any ideas?
[image]
OBS: these bottom horizontal lines (original object) are belzier with vector handle type.

OBS2: yes, I could only duplicate the bottom line, but that would'nt be ideal to my workflow I think.

---

I mean this: in this example there are 4 points, but they are currently in the same position and they travel along the first stack only with the 'sample curve' node factor. I wished that the four points were distributed to the four stacks and they were guided with the 'sample curve' node factor. Is there a way to do that? Then the points would be the position source for the horizontal line, in other words to build the horizontal stacks of the fence with custom height. An also, in the future be able to put many horizontal lines with different positions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls at least provide node tree - or even better: blend file. thx

Comment: *"yes, I could only duplicate the bottom line, but that would'nt be ideal to my workflow I think."* - **why?** Since this looks like a simple geometry, could you maybe manually create the input, and the output, to make it clearer what the geonodes setup is intended to do? As far as I understand now, you want to spawn vertical lines on points of a horizontal line, and then you want to also connect tops of these vertical lines (and since they're vertical, you really can simply duplicate the bottom and move it up).

Comment: It's difficult to tell right now because the project is in early stage, but I think I'll need to do that later on for a different purpose where I won't have this bottom line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I figured it out!
[image]
It was right before my nose! There will be more stuff to think about later on, like how to make more horizontal lines and sync the factor with a delay on each line. I wonder if the loop nodes are going to help in this sense when Blender 4.0 launches? Would be incredible!
Thanks for the help it really made the difference!

Answer (score 4):

Given a starting curve (can be mesh, can be bare points, though vertices/points have to be in proper order) you can spawn instances of a vertical curve on them (what you have so far), but then you can realize those instances, delete everything but their ends, duplicate the starting curve (this time I assume it's a curve or mesh edges, but you could just spawn a new curve and resample to have the correct number of points), and set point positions to just prepared geometry in one-to-one relation (sample by index).

[image]

[image]

You could do it without deleting geometry, by calculating the index to sample (current index multiplied by the number of points in the vertical curve), or you could even do it without realizing instances like so:

[image]

The latter option, however, doesn't take care of eventual rotations and scale of the instances. You could still use vector rotate, and mix to take care of that, it wouldn't be hard, but since you don't hit some performance issues, I'd say if you want rotations, then simply use the first solution, and keep the node tree simple.

Comment: The result is great but, I wonder, is that a way to make the curve to travel along the stacks with a factor? that would be great! I think perhaps with a sample curve or a spline parameter would do somehow?

Comment: @AAAYerus I don't know what you mean by "traveling along the stacks with a factor".